# "Not if but when ..." and "Not when but if ..."

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

In English, there are sometimes exchanges like the following:

> 1. Person A: If Bob finishes his thesis, ...
> 2. Person B: *When* Bob finishes his thesis ...

The effect of B's response to A, and their use of the word *when*, indicates that Bob will finish their thesis and that this is not in question.

Similarly, in the other direction, we get exchanges like the following:

> 3. Person A: When Bob finishes their thesis, ...
> 4. Person B: *If* Bob finishes their theses, ...

Here, B's use of *if* calls into question the idea that Bob will definitely finish their thesis.

I assume that it's possible to make the same kind of distinctions in German, but how do speakers do this? My school-learned German has the same word, *wenn* used for the English senses of both *if* and *when*.

Comment: German has all three possibilities. 'sobald' means something will definitely happen, 'falls' means that something will probably not happen, and 'wenn' can mean both. But since 'wenn' is by far the most common word, this particular conversational trope just isn't very common in German.

Comment: Maybe this is just my local (swiss) impression, but if a friend says "Wenn Bob seine Arbeit abgibt" I will usually assume "when" is meant and I might interject "*Wenn* Bob seine Arbeit abgibt" with spoken emphasis on the "Wenn" to say "*If* he indeed does hand the thesis in".

Comment: I partly agree with @lucidbrot, that it depends on emphasis, and partly I think, that this goes way deeper. I tried to think of a few completions to "When Bob finishes his thesis", and everything I came up with (we'll party, his father will buy him a car, he will start a job at XYZ), is something I'd rather phrase as "Wenn Bob seine Arbeit *abgegeben hat*" instead of "abgibt". But I wonder if that's just me or anybody else, too?

Comment: @Sabine What you suggest is more usual imo too, but means something different. "Wenn Bob seine Arbeit abgegeben hat" means "after he handed it in" whereas "Wenn Bob seine Arbeit abgibt" means "when he hands it something happens at the same time"

Answer (score 9):

It's true that *wenn* has multiple meanings in German and can be ambiguous if there is not enough context. This is true of most common words. But it's also true that most common words have synonyms that make the meaning clear when in doubt. Of course synonyms can change the connotations of a sentence, but some slight differences in meaning are nearly always unavoidable when translating between languages.

In this case, you could use *falls* = "in case" or *sofern* = "provided (that)" for "if". And you could *sobald* = "as soon as" for "when". There are other options available as well, but I think these are the most common. A good thesaurus is helpful for this kind of thing; [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wenn) provides this kind of information but they link to OpenThesaurus for a source. DeepL can work as well since it provides alternate translations and usage examples when you highlight a word.

It might be worth mentioning *Wenn man vom Teufel spricht.* = "Speak of the devel." I'm not sure if "if" or "when" is meant in this case, but I have a feeling not many people really care.

Comment: 'Wenn man vom Teufel spricht' is definitely 'when'.

Comment: I think I have used the combinations OP is asking about in German using 'falls' for 'if' and 'wenn' for 'when'.

Answer (score 7):

I would usually phrase this kind of reply by the similar construction of [constrasting with *ob*](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=nicht+wenn%2C+sondern+ob&ia=web):

> A: Wenn Bob mit seiner Diplomarbeit fertig ist...
>
> B: Die Frage ist aber nicht *wann*, sondern *ob*!

IMHO *wann* and *wenn* are related and perceived as closely enough for this to work (in my dialect, they even fall together).  I'd even be tempted to say *nicht wenn, sondern ob*, but this has a weird feeling when thinking more about it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a word that strictly means "if" in this context: "falls". However, "wenn" indeed can mean both "if" and "when".

So, your first example wouldn't really occur in German because the ambiguous "wenn" would be more commonly used unless the first person really wants to emphasize "if".

Your second example could be "Wenn ... *Falls* ..." but is also not that common. If I was the second person there, I might say something like "Glaubst du wirklich, er wird jemals fertig?"

Comment: "your first example wouldn't really occur in German" -- I was thinking about how exactly you'd translate the above exchanges into German. It seems like it would be tricky and a complete rephrase might be in order.

Comment: @RDBury If you need to translate, you'd use "Falls ... Sobald ..." or something like that. But this dialogue wouldn't occur naturally.

Comment: For the second construction in OPs question I would use 'wenn' and 'falls' in German without fear of confusion. For the first one it is a little more tricky but in context wenn und falls would still convey the correct meaning.